# How to create a link to a third-party Internet resource in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, html

How to create a link to a third-party Internet resource in LWC. Not to another LWC, not to any object associated with LWC or Salesforce, but for example to https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm . I just need to redirect/go to another page. If it was regular HTML it would be `<a href="URL">...</a>`, but I can't find a suitable tag for LWC.

Comment: Standard tags are always good if you don't need extra features provided by standard LWC components. `<a href="URL">...</a>` works in LWC too, did you try it?

Comment: No, I'll try it now

Comment: You're right, it works

Comment: @RubenDG Consider posting your comment as answer as it has helped OP in resolving the issue :)

Comment: @Raul done, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard HTML tags are always good if you don't need extra features provided by standard LWC components.
In your case the [anchor element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a), `<a href="URL">...</a>`, will be fine.

Comment: By the way, in LWC I also found the tag `<lightning-formatted-url value="http://yourURL.com " label="The text of the link in on the page"></lightning-formatted-url>` which performs the same functions as the tag `<a href="url" ....>...</ a>`, documentation : [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-url/example)